# Inno Setup BrowseForFolder dialog with Address bar

Tags: inno-setup

When I use the `BrowseForFolder` function in Inno Setup I get a dialog like this

[image]

Is it possible to get a dialog with an address bar such as this one?

[image]

Comment: Not without modifying the source code.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`TInputDirWizardPage`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TInputDirWizardPage) ([`CreateInputDirPage`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createinputdirpage)), instead of using the `BrowseForFolder` function.

The page has the browse dialog as you want (actually I assume your second screenshot shows this dialog).

---

If you do not want to add a new page, just create a fake one and abuse it.

```pascal
var
  FakePage: TInputDirWizardPage;

procedure BrowseForFolderEx(var Directory: String);
begin
  FakePage.Values[0] := Directory;
  FakePage.Buttons[0].OnClick(FakePage.Buttons[0]);
  Directory := FakePage.Values[0];
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  FakePage :=
    CreateInputDirPage(wpWelcome, '', '', '', False, SetupMessage(msgButtonNewFolder));
  FakePage.Add('');
end;

function ShouldSkipPage(PageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (PageID = FakePage.ID);
end;
```